# Searching for a term in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to extract my bank balance number from an email into Google Spreadsheets. So far I have a Google script grabbing the email, then pasting it into a Google spreadsheet in rawcontent form. You can see below the RawContent that is being pasted. (*This is not my bank balance or card it is a template that has been used and taken off my bank's website for a draft of what the email would look like.*)

```
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Received: by 10.79.112.196 with HTTP; Tue, 20 Oct 2015 18:13:30 -0700 (PDT)
    Date: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 02:13:30 +0100
    Delivered-To: liamnagle5@gmail.com
    Message-ID: <CAL9nrMo3OXzMsPUMpXjOO1AEg_u72czoYLEQLeWz emRfJ0tfw@mail.gmail.com>
    Subject: BB TEST
    From: Liam Nagle <liamnagle5@gmail.com>
    To: Liam Nagle <liamnagle5@gmail.com>
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a114d944e1c2fac052293164b

    --001a114d944e1c2fac052293164b
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

    Dear Mr. Broe,

    Your weekly account summary for
    account ending 6920 is below:

    Current Balance as at 12:30 26 Sep:
    =C2=A32500.00+
    Available Balance as at 12:30 26 Sep:
    =C2=A32700.00+

    RECENT TRANSACTIONS:
    25Sep Transfer =C2=A310.59-
    25Sep Cheque deposit 150.00+
    24Sep Direct Debit =C2=A33.60-
    23Sep Standing order =C2=A323.50-
    21Sep CC payment =C2=A349.00-

    Regards,

    Santander Alerts

    --001a114d944e1c2fac052293164b
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

    <div dir=3D"ltr"><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,=
    Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-=
    height:17.9952px">Dear Mr. Broe,</span><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(10=
    2,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px=
    ;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><br style=3D"margin:0px;co=
    lor:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-si=
    ze:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><span style=3D"c=
    olor:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-s=
    ize:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px">Your weekly acc=
    ount summary for</span><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-=
    family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:=
    -0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font=
    -family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing=
    :-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px">account ending 6920 is below:</span><br s=
    tyle=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helveti=
    ca,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.995=
    2px"><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Ari=
    al,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-hei=
    ght:17.9952px"><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Ar=
    ial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-he=
    ight:17.9952px">Current Balance as at 12:30 26 Sep:=C2=A0</span><br style=
    =3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,s=
    ans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"=
    ><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,=
    sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px=
    ">=C2=A32500.00+</span><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-=
    family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:=
    -0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font=
    -family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing=
    :-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px">Available Balance as at 12:30 26 Sep:=C2=
    =A0</span><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdan=
    a,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;lin=
    e-height:17.9952px"><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verda=
    na,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;li=
    ne-height:17.9952px">=C2=A32700.00+</span><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb=
    (102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.0=
    4px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><br style=3D"margin:0px=
    ;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font=
    -size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><span style=
    =3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;f=
    ont-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px">RECENT TRA=
    NSACTIONS:</span><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family=
    :Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.110=
    4px;line-height:17.9952px"><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-famil=
    y:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.11=
    04px;line-height:17.9952px">25Sep Transfer =C2=A310.59-</span><br style=3D"=
    margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-=
    serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><sp=
    an style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans=
    -serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px">25=
    Sep Cheque deposit 150.00+</span><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,=
    102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;lette=
    r-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102=
    ,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;lett=
    er-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px">24Sep Direct Debit =C2=A33.60-<=
    /span><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Ar=
    ial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-he=
    ight:17.9952px"><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,A=
    rial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-h=
    eight:17.9952px">23Sep Standing order =C2=A323.50-</span><br style=3D"margi=
    n:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif=
    ;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><span st=
    yle=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-seri=
    f;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px">21Sep C=
    C payment =C2=A349.00-</span><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102)=
    ;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-sp=
    acing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(10=
    2,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px=
    ;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"><span style=3D"color:rgb(1=
    02,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04p=
    x;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px">Regards,</span><br style=
    =3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,s=
    ans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:17.9952px"=
    ><br style=3D"margin:0px;color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,H=
    elvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height:=
    17.9952px"><span style=3D"color:rgb(102,102,102);font-family:Verdana,Arial,=
    Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:11.04px;letter-spacing:-0.1104px;line-height=
    :17.9952px">Santander Alerts</span></div>

    --001a114d944e1c2fac052293164b--
```

What I am hoping to get out of this is where it says:

```
    Current Balance as at 12:30 26 Sep:
    =C2=A32500.00+
    Available Balance as at 12:30 26 Sep:
    =C2=A32700.00+
```

From here i would like to extract the numbers `2500.00` and `2700.00`. The `=C2=A3` part is denoting a `£` written in RawContent form. After extracting the two numbers I am hoping to assign these to two cells on another sheet to then use that data to work out financial plans etc.

Comment: well is it not the same coding? Seems like it too me from my excel knowledge

Comment: Well i didnt know that. I'll delete the tag.

Comment: How is the raw content being pasted? Is it all in one cell or is it spread out over multiple cells?

Comment: All in one cell. I have no idea how to make it paste to more than one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula `=REGEXEXTRACT(E4,"=C2=A3(\d+\.\d{2})\+")` to get the first match but the second will be a bit trickier.
Since you are already using a script I would write another quick function to extract those values.

```
function getBalance(){
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var re = /=C2=A3(\d+\.\d{2})\+/g;
  var results = [re.exec(data)[1], re.exec(data)[1]];
  return results;
}
```

This will get the text, extract the two available balances by identifying them with the raw £ prefix and return them in an array.

You can then even run `=GETBALANCE()` from the spreadsheet and it will give you the balances as output in two separate rows.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with REGEXTRACT! Just couldnt get my head around what. I'll test this out now!

Comment: If this helped you can you accept the answer so people in the future can easily see it? Thanks

Comment: Ok so i've had to change this around a little bit the part where you had '/=C2=A' written which denotes '£' has now changed to just a pound symbol. In the code if i change this to a '£' symbol however the sheet is not updated with my balance? Is there a way to change this to make it work?

Comment: `/\p{Sc}(\d+\.\d{2})\+/g` and `/\u00A3(\d+\.\d{2})\+/g` both don't seem to work which is odd (The former should work for Google's RE2, the latter for JS's engine. Since the balance seems to be the first two numbers would it be safe to just run `(\d+\.\d{2})[\+|\-]` and use the first two results? (I added support for negative balances)

Comment: I believe it is the second two numbers (There is my account number ending in ****) at the start of the notification. How would i change this?

Comment: Also inserting `(\d+\.\d{2})[\+|\-]` into my sheet in replacement for the above does nothing?

Comment: The account number is not formatted with decimals and has no + or - at the end so it worn't be capture. Weird that it doesn't work for you, I can use it in the script and as a Sheetformula and it works just fine. What's your function body now?

Comment: Looks like this 
`function getBalance(){
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue();
var re = (\d+\.\d{2})[\+|\-];
var results = [re.exec(data)[1], re.exec(data)[1]];
return results;` 
but it chucks an error out saying Illegal Character on the line where i have inserted the `(\d+\.\d{2})[\+|\-]`

Comment: The regex needs to be encapsulated between two `/` so `/(\d+\.\d{2})[\+|\-]/`, sorry